# error: type Call does not take parameters

Tags: java, android

Type 'android.telecom.Call' does not have type parameters

Call call;

```
call = apiInterface.getNews(country, API_KEY);

call.enqueue(new Callback<News>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
```

Comment: You should use Retrofit's Call instead of telecom

Comment: did checked my answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just verify that you've imported the correct package from Retrofit.
The correct one is `retrofit2.Call`, not to be confused with, for example, `android.telecom.Call`

Comment: wow thanks man ...."import android.telecom.Call;" was the problem until i removed it then "retrofit2.Call" was activated

Comment: Please consider my answer if it was helpful